# UPDATE Class not found Exception (MySQL drivers) using a Servlet and Prepared Statement

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

So thanks to the advices bellow I changed my first approach of using statements to using Prepared Statements , I also separated the verifyUser method from the ConnectDB to put it in a new user class (which is asked in my assignment).

Now I don't any NPE anymore but another one which is the Class Not Found Exception for the MySQL JDBC Driver.

The code is as follow for the Users class :

```
public class Users {

private String login;
private String password;


public Users(String login, String password) {
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setUsername(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public boolean verifyUser(String login, String password) throws SQLException {

    ConnectDB cdb = new ConnectDB();

    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(cdb.url, cdb.login, cdb.password);

    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT password FROM users WHERE login LIKE ? ");

ps.setString(1,username);

    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

    rs.next();

    if (rs.getString(2).equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        return true;
    }

    else
        return false;
}
}
```

This is my ConnectDB class :

```
public class ConnectDB {

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/entreprise";
String login = "root";
String password = "kamoulox369";
Connection connection = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;

public  void getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.example.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

And to put it all together , where it is used in the Servlet :

```
private void versIndex(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {

    String login = request.getParameter("user");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Users user = new Users(login,password);
    ConnectDB cdb = new ConnectDB();
    cdb.getConnection();

    if (user.verifyUser(login, password)) {

        RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

And of course the Error I'm getting :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
at com.example.ConnectDB.getConnection(ConnectDB.java:16)
at com.example.Servlet.versIndex(Servlet.java:111)
at com.example.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)


at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/entreprise
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at com.example.Users.verifyUser(Users.java:36)
    at com.example.Servlet.versIndex(Servlet.java:113)
    at com.example.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:41)
```

Comment: Please add full exception stacktrace to the question. Have you checked logs for other exceptions/ You have `e.printStackTrace();` when you try to get connection. So if exception is thrown both `connection` and `st` will be `null`

Comment: Okay I'll update the post when I get home I'm not able to right now,sorry. What do you suggest about the print stack trace? I have to say I haven't got a very good explanation about it when I was told to use it.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` prints information about exception to log file. But if you do not check your log file you will never know that exception occured

Comment: Okay noted thanks for the info , I just got back and updated my post to include the error report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s nothing simple about servlets or jdbc. They’re both error-prone.

You have a concurrency issue, resource issues where you’re not closing anything (including stranding connections), and also a sql injection vulnerability.

Using static members here is disastrous. Each request executes on a different thread and they will all overwrite objects being used by other threads. Each request should be handled using local variables.

Database connections never get closed, your database will run out of connections and stop working at some point. Close all jdbc objects when you’re done with them.

Concatenating user-entered input into the sql you run allows the user to get in without a valid password or run arbitrary sql. Use PreparedStatement.

Comment: Okay thank you for all the input ! I was aware about closing the database after use and all of that but didn't know the consequences of it , atm I was just trying to make the basics work before focusing on the extra stuff , there is indeed a lot of things to take into account to make a good code for that and I'm learning a little bit more everytime. The prepared statement does look like it could fit a lot better indeed from what I am seeing. I'll try that out. Do you have an idea why in that case , outside of all other considerations I'm getting this kind of exception?

Comment: @user9999270: the concurrency issue is likely causing the exception, the NPE is thrown when reading the st field.

Comment: As you suggested I changed my statement to a prepared statement and it indeed solved the NPE , I also tried to change my static fields and instatiate objects to use them instead of calling methods directly from static. I am now getting a Class not Found Exception for my MySQL drivers. So looking into that. I updated my OP if you wanna look into it , thanks again for your input.

Comment: @user9999270: The class used in the Class.forName looks bogus. More recent jdbc versions don’t need the Class.forName at all.

Comment: Hey , I finally managed to make it work the way I want to , it was mostly due to the fact that I had to put my JDBC drivers in the WEB-INF folder to be sure it was used. I didn't have to do that when I was doing it in SE(just put it in the External Libraries of Intellij) , so wasn't aware this could still be an issue. But thanks to you I got a lot better with Prepared Statements and I think it's better to use this way than the other one. Just a question is there cases where it's better to use statements rather than prepared ones ?

Comment: @user9999270: yes if there are no parameters. Jdbc driver goes in tomcat shared lib.